# Kotlin - How do I await for this coroutine to finish before proceeding?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have asynchronous code that uses the network to get a `companyName.` This `companyName` is used in another method call. I am unsure of how android currently properly waits for an async call to finish before proceeding with the other code. I saw making a job using

```
val job = launch {
   // async code 
   companyName = getCompanyName(stock)
}
job.join()
// Do stuff with companyName
```

but that no longer seems to be the paradigm as I get an error not using a `CoroutineScope.` So how do I wait for a coroutine to finish running before proceeding with other code (without using runBlocking {})?

Here is my code:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.currentStock.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { stock ->
            // TODO: change this to be company name
            var companyName = ""
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    companyName = getCompanyName(stock)
                }
            }
            deleteTable()
            getData(companyName)  // RELIES ON COMPANYNAME
        }
    }
```

`getData(companyName)` is defined as

```
 private suspend fun finraGetCfruid(companyName: String): String {
        val url = "https://www.finra.org/finra-data/fixed-income/corp-and-agency"

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireActivity())
        var cfruid = ""

        val stringRequest = object: StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            {
            },
            { error ->
                Log.e("Error", error.toString())
            })
        {
            override fun  parseNetworkResponse(response : NetworkResponse) : Response<String> {
                val cookies = HttpCookie.parse(response.headers?.get("Set-Cookie"))
                val indexOfEqualSign = cookies[0].toString().indexOf('=')
                cfruid = cookies[0].toString().substring(indexOfEqualSign + 1)

                datainterface.getMoreData(companyName, cfruid)

                return super.parseNetworkResponse(response)
            }
        }

        queue.add(stringRequest)

        return cfruid
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your code that happens after inside your coroutine. The code inside a coroutine  (the `launch` lambda) is synchronous. The launched coroutine itself is asynchronous to the code outside of it.

And, assuming you are touching views with this coroutine, you need to use the `viewLifecycleOwner`'s `lifecycleScope`, not the Fragment's. (If you're not working with views in this coroutine, it probably shouldn't be in the Fragment in the first place.)

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel.currentStock.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { stock ->
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            val companyName = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                getCompanyName(stock)
            }
            deleteTable()
            getData(companyName) 
        }
    }
}
```

If `getCompanyName` is a suspend function (and properly implemented) you don't need the `withContext`:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel.currentStock.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { stock ->
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
            val companyName = getCompanyName(stock)
            deleteTable()
            getData(companyName) 
        }
    }
}
```

You might consider an intermediate flow for less nested/repetitive code. This will also prevent a possible race condition. Launched coroutines from the LiveData observer could potentially run in parallel if two values arrive quickly in succession which might cause bugs depending on what you're doing in this coroutine. But Flow operators are processed sequentially so that cannot happen. Depending on what exactly you're doing, you might be able to further optimize this to avoid wasting time on obsolete items by replacing `onEach` with `transformLatest`. That would cause it to cancel the work its doing on the previous item early when a new item arrives quickly.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel.currentStock.asFlow()
        .onEach { stock ->
            val companyName = getCompanyName(stock)
            deleteTable()
            getData(companyName) 
        }
        .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
}
```

---

I'm not familiar with Volley, and just briefly browsed the documentation. It looks to me like you are using a StringRequest subclass to directly work with the response in the overridden `parseNetworkResponse()` function. So to convert that to a suspend function, I think it would look like:

```
suspend fun RequestQueue.awaitNetworkResponse(method: Int, url: String): NetworkResponse = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    val request = object: StringRequest(
        method,
        url,
        {},
        { continuation.resumeWithException(it) }
    ) {
         override fun  parseNetworkResponse(response : NetworkResponse) : Response<String> {
             continuation.resume(response)
             return super.parseNetworkResponse(response)
         }
    }
    add(request)
    continuation.invokeOnCancellation {
        request.cancel()
    }
}
```

Now you can use this function synchronously in a coroutine:

```
private suspend fun finraGetCfruid(companyName: String): String {
    val url = "https://www.finra.org/finra-data/fixed-income/corp-and-agency"

    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireActivity())
    val response = try {
        queue.awaitNetworkResponse(Request.Method.GET, url)
    } catch (e: VolleyError) {
        Log.e("Error", error.toString())
        return "" // or some other behavior?
    }
    val cookies = HttpCookie.parse(response.headers?.get("Set-Cookie"))
    val indexOfEqualSign = cookies[0].toString().indexOf('=')
    val cfruid = cookies[0].toString().substring(indexOfEqualSign + 1)
    datainterface.getMoreData(companyName, cfruid)
    return cfruid
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, this helps a lot. I forgot to mention `getData` is asynchronous as well. It still seems to be running before `getCompanyName` finishes.

Comment: I like the `Flow` look the best. It makes a lot more intuitive sense.

Comment: Sounds like it needs to be converted to a suspend function to make it synchronous. If you're unsure how, add it to your question and I'll take a look.

Comment: `getData` was a volley request (which I am looking to replace with okhttp soon). I will edit my answer now.

Comment: I added my attempt at converting it, but I'm not familiar with Volley.

Comment: for the awaitClose block I get ```Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public suspend fun ProducerScope<*>.awaitClose(block: () → Unit = ...): Unit defined in kotlinx.coroutines.channels``` despite importing it from `import kotlinx.coroutines.channels.awaitClose`. How do I edit it?

Comment: Sorry, wrong function! `awaitClose` is for the somewhat similar `callbackFlow` builder. Use `continuation.invokeOnCancellation` instead.

Comment: its still not applying that `companyName` to `getData`. let me play around with it and get back to you tomorrow with my findings.

Comment: Sounds like `getCompanyName()` isn’t synchronous either.

Comment: Darn, yeah. getCompanyName() is a coroutine as well. A simplier volley request but one none the less. SIgh. Can I just await that or something simple?

Comment: Shouldn't it run as if it was synchronous within the launch scope ie `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {}`

Comment: Asynchronous code can only run synchronously in coroutines by converting it to synchronous suspending code using `suspendCancellableCoroutine` or (less often) `suspendCoroutine`.

Comment: would using okhttp solve this issue because okhttp automatically puts the work on a background thread?

Comment: Volley and okhttp both do work on background threads automatically. The problem is whether they do it synchronously versus asynchronously. It can only be done synchronously with coroutines. Volley doesn't have coroutine support, so you have to build your own suspend functions using `suspendCancellableCoroutine` (unless there's a third party library out there that does it). Retrofit (the higher level library over okhttp) has coroutine support built in--you can define your requests as suspend functions to make them synchronous instead of returning an asynchronous `Call`.

Comment: The alternative to doing this synchronously with coroutines is to put all your code that's supposed to happen after inside the asynchronous callback. If you need to do this in a separate function, then your separate function needs to define its own callback. You end up with highly nested code inside callbacks that's hard to read, but that is how things have to be done in Java, which the Volley library was written for.

Comment: Let me switch it to okhttp and get back to you!

Comment: I think OKhttp is lower level than Volley and Retrofit is more comparable. It’s made by the same developers and uses OKhttp under the hood.

Comment: So which would you suggest? I do need slightly low level stuff to get `cfruid`

Comment: Then Okhttp is probably fine. I'm not an expert either way.